# How to insert a long table in main text frame to break and re-flow to the next page

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

I'm working on a file where I have a fairly long table. Because the table is long, it needs to reflow to the next page. I know how to specify the top cell as a header so when it's cut short, the header reappears on the next box (see table on the right). But the part I'm having a problem is to put this in the main text frame to reflow.

Once I insert my table in the main text frame, it won't let me click on that little red plus sign icon that appears at the bottom right of the table when the frame is not big enough to show all the info that contains (see image on left).

I've tried creating two flowing boxes outside of the main frame and pasted in but then the second box loses the linkage to the first box.

Is there a way to put flowing tables into a text frame so everything re-flows if we make edits to the file? or is this double reflow not possible? I'm using CS6 btw.

[image]
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You're doing it correctly. It should flow just like text. No clue why that's not working for you. Perhaps you aren't clicking that little (ridiculously little) red + accurately? Or there's another element interfering with your click? Shorten the box a little and try again.

Comment: I'm sure I could fix this if I saw the actual INDD file, otherwise there are a number of things which can go wrong here. Upload these 2 pages somewhere?

Comment: Strange thing. Obviously you need to select the text frame before being able to thread it, with the appropriate tool (Selection). Frame isn't selected in your screenshot. But you seem to be experienced enough to know that. So, my guess is that your file may be corrupted. Try saving as IDML, open the .idml doc and see what happens.  As Lucian suggested, you can also share your doc somehow so we could have a look at it. (Btw, do you use automatic re-flow feature?)